# Should newly password links reset old ones? if so, why?

Tags: password-management, password-reset

I have noticed on most websites that all previous password reset links are automatically expired when a new one is requested.

Why is this so common and what are some possible consequences if this isn't done?

Comment: Having multiple valid reset links only increases the surface attack with no benefit for the user. Plus, if the user is requesting a new reset link it's because they cannot use a previous one. Maybe because it has been delayed by the MTA or has been stolen. In any case, invalidating these no longer-needed links is the best choice.

Comment: @MargaretBloom what's the possible hazard?

Comment: @schroeder Basically what CBHacking said. Specifically, the fact that you can revoke a (possibly) stolen link by generating a new one. But, true, it's not a very strong argument.

Comment: if it has been delayed by the it may still arrive before the replacement link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple non-security reason is that it lets you have a single field in your Users table for "password reset token" which is populated when it's valid and generating a new one for a given user overwrites any existing one for that user.

From a security perspective, there's not a very strong argument either way. Having multiple tokens active at once technically increases the risk of somebody guessing/brute-forcing one, but that risk should be so infinitesimal that the server would run out of storage space before it could hold enough to make that a risk at all worth considering. A bigger factor is that there's no other easy way to invalidate a password reset link, so if you suspect the link (or at least the token part) was exposed, being able to render it useless by generating another one is valuable. On the other hand, this does pose a small denial-of-service risk; a malicious user could repeatedly generate password reset links for a given account, at a rate where the links constantly expire before you can use them, such that the user is never able to log in because they can never reset their password. On the other hand, sending password reset links is already behavior that needs abuse prevention, and the threat of targeted single-use DoS is pretty minimal anyhow.